# Doing an addition from a JSON value which is a number and replace it by the result

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

I need to manipulate a JSON value which is a number.

I tried this, but without any result:

```js
let picture = require('./pictures.json');
        
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#fdafb5')
.setDescription(picture['pic01'].description)
.addField("❤ Likes:", picture['pic01'].likes)
.setImage(picture['pic01'].image)
.setFooter("Source: " + picture['pic01'].source)
.setTimestamp()

let authorCommandMessage = message.author.id;

message.channel.send(embed).then(message => {
    message.react('❤');

    message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id === authorCommandMessage && (reaction.emoji.name === '❤'), { max: 1, time: 30000 })
        .then(collected => {
            if(collected.first().emoji.name === '❤'){
                picture['pic01'].likes + 1;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

*(Here's the JSON if needed:)*

```json
{
    "pic01":
        {
            "likes":0,
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simon Cheng's answer is correct, assignment is necessary.

```
// Assign +1 value to the current property.
picture['pic01'].likes += 1;

// This will do the same as above, but less elegantly.
picture['pic01'].likes = picture['pic01'].likes + 1;
```

Here's a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skqh931x/) showing how it works.

I noticed you're doing this assignment inside a possibly **asynchronous routine**. Please keep in mind that the side effect of changing the `likes` property will only happen after this routine does what it needs to do, and you must read the object after it completed.

And, just to be sure, if you're trying to change the JSON file itself, you'd need to add a read/write mechanic. Currently, you're reading the JSON file and creating a copy of it as a JS Object inside your runtime - therefore, changes made to this copy will not affect the JSON file.

Answer (score 2):

you need to assign the calculated value back to the json.

change

```js
picture['pic01'].likes + 1;
```

to

```js
picture['pic01'].likes = picture['pic01'].likes + 1;
```

or even better,

```js
picture['pic01'].likes += 1;
```

Comment: I already tried doing `picture['pic01'].likes += 1;` but it didn't gave any result too, same for `picture['pic01'].likes = picture['pic01'].likes + 1;`.

Comment: what is the result you are looking for? Your question is really unclear and I don't understand your intent.

Comment: I just want that when user react with ❤ it adds 1 to the likes of pic01 from pictures.json

Comment: are you trying to update the field in `.addField("❤ Likes:", picture['pic01'].likes)`? you will need to manually edit the embed after you update the json value

Comment: No, I'm not trying to update the value in the field but in the JSON file.

Comment: `you need to assign the calculated value back to the json.` there is nothing in the code that would change the read in JSON. `let picture = require('./pictures.json');` reads the JSON encoded data that is stored in `pictures.json` parses it and stores that parsed data in `picture`. `picture` is not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to resolve my problem (thanks to mdeamf for telling me that I need to write the file and Simon Cheng for telling me how to do the addition).

```js
let picture = require('./pictures.json');

let pictures = ['pic01'];
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * pictures.length);
        
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#fdafb5')

.setDescription(picture[pictures[random]].description)
.addField("❤ Likes:", picture[pictures[random]].likes)
.setImage(picture[pictures[random]].image)
.setFooter("Source: " + picture[pictures[random]].source)
.setTimestamp()

let authorCommandMessage = message.author.id;

message.channel.send(embed).then(message => {
    message.react('❤');

    message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id === authorCommandMessage && (reaction.emoji.name === '❤'), { max: 1, time: 30000 })
        .then(collected => {
            if(collected.first().emoji.name === '❤'){
                picture[pictures[random]].likes = picture[pictures[random]].likes += 1;
                        
                fs.writeFileSync('pictures.json', JSON.stringify(picture, null, 2));
        }
    });
});
```